# Why does glewInit() give me a segfault?

Tags: c++11, opengl, segmentation-fault, glfw, glew

Im working on a project with opengl using glew and glfw

The project is larger but only the initialisation code doesnt work correctly. Im using glew 2.2.0_1 and glfw 3.3.8
(btw. I ran this in a debugger so Im 100% sure the glewInit() is causing the segfault. And if I put this in a file without the rest of the code its also causing a segfault)

The code is:

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const int WIDTH = 640;
const int HEIGHT = 480;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Set up GLFW and create window
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Spinning Cube", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!window) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Set up GLEW
    glewInit();
    // ...
}
```

Is it a library error or am I doing something wrong? (For anybody asking this code compiles without any warnings or errors)

Comment: What is you OS? Mac? If yes, add `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);`

Comment: What version of GLEW are you using? Apparently there was a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/glew/patches/40/) in earlier versions with core profile and windows.

Comment: Is that really your code? Any time window creation succeeds (and thus returns a valid window pointer), the return statement is executed. So if you reach glewInit, then window creation has already failed.

Comment: @AspectOfTheNoob im using version 2.2.0_1 Ive read that the bug was fixed in 2.0 but another user helped me out on this and it works now thanks

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks Im actually on macos so this works just fine thnak you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the **macOS** operating system, you must create an OpenGL Core Profile context with the forward compatibility flag set:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
```

Comment: @Guichi I talk about `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);` which is essential in macOS